# premake5 variable name for workspace and project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I wanted to make the process of creating **premake5** file easier by automating the process of creating a **premake5** file. when I tried to put a variable `ProjectName = "myProject"` into where the name of the workspace was supposed to be `workspace ProjectName`. it gave me an error. I also put it into the project and the location of the project but that doesn't work either `project ProjectName`, `location ProjectName`. I wonder if there is a way I can do this. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this, you simply just need to put a bracket around the name variable `ProjectName` like this `workspace (ProjectName)`! today, I just came back to the script and start experimenting and it works!